# How to define function on click, after element append in dynamically or (setTimeInterval)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made on click function for dynamic elements but its not working, Is there a way around it?

```
$( "p" ).on( "myCustomEvent", function( event, myName ) {

  $( this ).text( myName + ", hi there!" );

  $( "span" )
    .stop()
    .css( "opacity", 1 )
    .text( "myName = " + myName )
    .fadeIn( 30 )
    .fadeOut( 5000 );
});

$( "button" ).click(function () {
  $( "p" ).trigger( "myCustomEvent", [ "John" ] );
  //alert(1);
});

var loop = setInterval(function(){
    $('.box').append('<button>Trigger custom event</button>');

},1000);

window.setTimeout(function(){ clearInterval(loop); },2000);
```

For code [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/rupesx26/txyLb3Ly/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code

you need to learn about [event-delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/txyLb3Ly/2/)

```
 $( document ).on('click',"button",function () {
  $( "p" ).trigger( "myCustomEvent", [ "John" ] );
 });
```

NOTE : you can use nearest static parent selector instead of `document`.

Comment: yes, I have added in my main file but problem is its working after 2nd click..

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/txyLb3Ly/5/  its working fine

Comment: if I used <div class="btn">Trigger custom event</div> this instead of "button" element then how to define it?

Comment: condition is only trigger "btn" and not outside area

Comment: use can use any tag to assign your custom event

Comment: see this example http://jsfiddle.net/txyLb3Ly/6/

Comment: ohh! .. :) its working

Comment: ya definitely .. .. but problem is still occur when you check this http://jsfiddle.net/rupesx26/475wz9q1/1/

Comment: which problem you face ?? it open pop up on click ?

Comment: on 1st click modal not open http://jsfiddle.net/rupesx26/475wz9q1/1/ please check

Comment: check by uncomment alert .. it working your pop up us not opeaning